# Reading this output from Instruments in Leaks mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm new to memory management and have been playing around with Instruments in Leaks mode. This is my latest output and I was wondering if I could get some feedback from the SO community. It seems as if my total leak amount is quite high, even though the individual leaks are not that big (I think). Should I be concerned? Should I be looking to get rid of all of these leaks?

N.B. The app runs on the iPhone and doesn't use any network.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen you are looking at is not the Leaks. It is the memory allocations of your app.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I find the leaks?

Comment: In the bit that you cropped out of the image, where it says 'Leaks'

Comment: someone posted this earlier.. i dont know why it has been removed http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/